# Excel VBA Script Format Date MM-DD-YYYY

Tags: vba, excel, date, datetime

I'm need to convert the value of two cells from dd/mm/yyyy to mm-dd-yyyy and append the values to a stored procedure call. My code:

```
Dim dtInicio As String
Dim dtFim As String
Set stDate = CStr(MWS.Cells(1, "E").Value)
Set enDate = CStr(MWS.Cells(2, "E").Value)
```

I need something like this after the above code:

```
wstring = "exec sp_accessFile '"+stDate+"', '"+enDate +"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `Set` a date. Value assignment with an `=` is sufficient. Ampersands (e.g. `&`), not plus signs (e.g. `+`) are used for string concatenation.

The VBA `Format` function should be good at returning the correct string.

```
Dim dtInicio As String, dtFim As String
stDate = Format(MWS.Cells(1, "E").Value, "mm-dd-yyyy")
enDate = Format(MWS.Cells(2, "E").Value, "mm-dd-yyyy")

wstring = "exec sp_accessFile '" & stDate & "', '" & enDate & "'"
```

The `wstring` should look like,

> exec sp_accessFile '07-19-2015', '08-25-2015'

The above assumes that E1:E2 are actual dates.